# How to optionally run Java app with no window (stage)?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javafx, inno-setup

I have a Java application written in E(fx)clipse, which I am currently packaging using Ant.

I have set it up to run on startup. This is done in Win with a startup items shortcut created by inno setup, and by creating a plist for the Mac.

I would like the application to run in the background (ie without the main stage opening) when it's triggered to run during startup, and to open the main stage window only when manually run by the user (from Applications on Mac, or Program Files on Win).

Is this possible? If so, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you! :D

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "main stage window".  If you mean a console window, for Windows, there is `javaw.exe` for running java program w/o a console window and `java.exe` if you need a console window.  If that is not what you are talking about, then have your program support a command-line option to specify which mode to operate in, and then set that option in your startup shortcut.

Comment: Ah sorry, by "main stage",  I just meant window. I want it to run in the background without a window opening. Really, I think I've focused on the wrong aspect here, sorry! I know how to show/hide my window programmatically, what I'm having trouble with is how to send args when I  start my application on startup so I know whether or not I should be opening the window.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Still seems you should support a command-line switch on which mode to run as.  I.e.  If you add a shortcut to the Startup folder for your program, just have the shortcut pass a command-line option that indicates "startup mode".